# different mse result for training set

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, loss-function, mse

I get different results for `mse`. During trainig I get 0.296 after my last training epoch and when I evaluate my model I get 0.112. Does any one know why that is so?

Here is the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,batch_input_shape=(batch_size,look_back,dim_x)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(150,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history=model.fit(x_train_r, y_train_r, validation_data=(x_test_r, y_test_r),\
                  epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[es])

score_test = model.evaluate(x_test_r, y_test_r,batch_size=batch_size)
score_train = model.evaluate(x_train_r, y_train_r,batch_size=batch_size)

print("Score Training Data:")
print(score_train)
```

Batch size and everything stays the same. Does anyone knows why I get so different results for `mse`?

Comment: Could be a number of reasons: your training set is not representative of your test set, you are overfitting to the training set, you have a class imbalance, etc.  There are any number of reasons that could be driving the difference.

Comment: but what is more representative for the mse of my training set? I know that there is a difference between my test and training set but i use the same data for training so I am real curious where this big difference comes from. Do you know how i can figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the discrepancy between the training loss and the loss obtained on the training data after the training is finished, is the existence of `Dropout` layer in the model. That's because this layer has different behavior during training and inference time. As I have mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52760112/2099607), you can make this behavior the same either by passing `training=True` to dropout call, or using `K.learning_phase()` flag and a backend function.

Comment: Thanks very much :)