# Is dropout layer still active in a freezed Keras model (i.e. trainable=False)?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, dropout

I have two trained models (`model_A` and `model_B`), and both of them have dropout layers. I have freezed `model_A` and `model_B` and merged them with a new dense layer to get `model_AB` (but I have not removed `model_A`'s and `model_B`'s dropout layers). `model_AB`'s weights will be non-trainable, except for the added dense layer.

Now my question is: are the dropout layers in `model_A` and `model_B` active (i.e. drop neurons) when I am training `model_AB`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer:** The dropout layers will continue dropping neurons **during training**, even if you set their `trainable` property to `False`.

**Long answer:** There are two distinct notions in Keras:

- **Updating the weights and states of a layer:** this is controlled using `trainable` property of that layer, i.e. if you set `layer.trainable = False` then the weights and internal states of the layer would not be updated.
- **Behavior of a layer in training and testing phases:** as you know a layer, like dropout, may have a different behavior during training and testing phases. Learning phase in Keras is set using `keras.backend.set_learning_phase()`. For example, when you call `model.fit(...)` the learning phase is automatically set to 1 (i.e. training), whereas when you use `model.predict(...)` it will be automatically set to 0 (i.e. test). Further, note that learning phase of 1 (i.e. training) does not necessarily imply updating the weighs/states of a layer. You can run your model with a learning phase of 1 (i.e. training phase), but no weights will be updated; just layers will switch to their training behavior (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439143/2099607) for more information). Further, there is another way to set learning phase for each individual layer by passing `training=True` argument when calling a layer on a tensor (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52760112/2099607) for more information).

So according to the above points, when you set `trainable=False` on a dropout layer and use that in training mode (e.g. either by calling `model.fit(...)`, or manually setting learning phase to training like example below), the neurons would still be dropped by the dropout layer.

Here is a reproducible example which illustrates this point:

```py
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

inp = layers.Input(shape=(10,))
out = layers.Dropout(0.5)(inp)

model = models.Model(inp, out)
model.layers[-1].trainable = False  # set dropout layer as non-trainable
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse') # IMPORTANT: we must always compile model after changing `trainable` attribute

# create a custom backend function so that we can control the learning phase
func = K.function(model.inputs + [K.learning_phase()], model.outputs)

x = np.ones((1,10))
# learning phase = 1, i.e. training mode
print(func([x, 1]))
# the output will be:
[array([[2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)]
# as you can see some of the neurons have been dropped

# now set learning phase = 0, i.e test mode
print(func([x, 0]))
# the output will be:
[array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)]
# unsurprisingly, no neurons have been dropped in test phase
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dropout layer randomly sets input units to 0 with a frequency of rate at each step during training time, which helps prevent overfitting. Inputs not set to 0 are scaled up by 1/(1 - rate) such that the sum over all inputs is unchanged.

Note that the Dropout layer only applies when training is set to True such that no values are dropped during inference. When using model.fit, training will be appropriately set to True automatically, and in other contexts, you can set the kwarg explicitly to True when calling the layer.

(This is in contrast to setting trainable=False for a Dropout layer. trainable does not affect the layer's behavior, as Dropout does not have any variables/weights that can be frozen during training.)

Check the official doc [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/)